# Finding gaps between the values of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, gaps-and-islands, mariadb-10.5

At a table of movie actors,

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistMap
(
ArtistID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
MovieID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
Year year,
INDEX(MovieID),
INDEX(Year),
PRIMARY KEY(ArtistID,MovieID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

How can I select movies of an artist before a gap of X year in their works?

For example,

```
ArtistID    MovieID    Year
1           1          1985
1           2          1987
1           3          2000
1           4          2001
1           5          2002
```

I want to get the fields before a gap of 10 years in the artist's works (the gap occurs between 1987-200 when the artist did not play any movie). I want to get

```
ArtistID    MovieID    Year
1           1          1985
1           2          1987
```

If there is more than one gap, the first one suffices.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEAD(year)` or `LAG(year)` to discover a gap of 10+ years.  Then use `ROW_NUMBER()` to keep rows before that gap.  (See "windowing functions", available since MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0.)

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but a tip that might be useful.)

In MariaDB,

```
SELECT  ...
    FROM seq_1985_to_2022 AS seq
    LEFT JOIN ArtistMap AS am  ON am.Year = seq.num
```

will provide all the years in that range.  Use `seq.num` for the "year"; `am.Year` will be `NULL` for the missing years.  Therefore, you can fetch just the missing years by adding

```
WHERE am.Year IS NULL
```

Or maybe you want counts or blanks for the missing years.  If so, use `COALESCE(...)` to turn `NULL` into `0` or blank.

**Gap of 10 years** -- Check the "gaps-and-islands" tag I added; it may help.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, it will catch any gap in the sequence, not a specific gap, e.g., X year (I mentioned 10 years in the example).

Comment: The pseudo-table provides all numbers in a desired range; after that, the `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` control what use you make of the "complete" set of numbers.  If you wanted only 10 years starting with 1985, either use `seq_1985_to_1994` or use, say, `seq_0_to_9999` together with `WHERE num BETWEEN 1985 AND 1994`.